# Angular 2 - How to pass routeparams in routerConfig without reloading the page

Tags: angular

How to pass routeparams in routerConfig without reloading the page

I have a component which is passing routerparams in the routerlink as follows

```
@Component({
    selector: 'apartment',
  template: `
   <div *ngFor="#apartment of apartments" class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">                
                <a [routerLink]="['AptDetails', {UnitType: apartment.UnitType, aptStatus: 'Available'}]" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="getAvailable(apartment)">Available</a>                            
              </div>
    </div>
```

In the receiving component the parameters are read as follows,

```
@Component({
    selector: 'aptdetails',
  template: ` <h1> Apt Details</h1>
              {{aptDetails | json}} 
    `,
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class AptDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private apartmentService: ApartmentService, private sharedService: SharedService, params: RouteParams) {
    this.apartmentService = apartmentService;
    this.aptStatus = params.get('aptStatus');
    this.UnitType = params.get('UnitType');    
    }
```

The values are passed successfully, but the page is refreshed.

How can I pass the parameters without refreshing the page in routerLink ?

I know that we can create a shared service for temporary storage of the values between components, How can I use routeparams for the same ?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement [CanReuse](https://angular.io/docs/js/latest/api/router/CanReuse-interface.html)

```
class MyComponent implements CanReuse {
  routerCanReuse(nextInstruction: ComponentInstruction, prevInstruction: ComponentInstruction) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

then navigating to the current route with only parameters changed does reuse the existing component instance.

Comment: Can I pass RouteName in ComponentInstruction like this directly ? `routerCanReuse(nextInstruction: 'AptDetails', prevInstruction: 'Apartment')`

Comment: No, the router is calling that method when it navigates to this component. You shouldn't call it yourself. You can use a `routerLink` or `router.navigateXxx(...)` call and the rest is done by the router.

Comment: The page is still reloading when it is going to AptDetails... .. maybe I'm doing something wrong. I added `CanReuse` in the ApartmentComponent which routes to AptDetails

Comment: Not sure what you are doing. The page never reloads when the route changes, that's the whole purpose of the router. `routerCanReuse` only prevents a component to be recreated when the route stays the same but parameters change.

Comment: The RouterConfig is having some problems http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37731914/angular2-routerconfig-subrouting-between-child-components?noredirect=1#comment62944539_37731914

Comment: How are you "going to AptDetails"?

Answer (score 0):

use CanReuse and OnReuse, as

```
export class Component implements  OnReuse, CanReuse {

    routerCanReuse() {
        if (yourCondition)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    routerOnReuse() {
        console.log('on reuse');
    }


}
```