# Angular2 - routerConfig subrouting between child components

Tags: angular

The sub-routing is having an issue with the page reloading between child components.

In app.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: 'app/businessunits/...', component: BusinessRootComponent, as: 'BusinessRoots' },
])
```

in BusinessRootComponent.ts

```
@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/', component: BusinessUnitComponent, as: 'BusinessUnit', useAsDefault: true },
    { path: '/apartment', component: ApartmentComponent, as: 'Apartment' },
    { path: '/aptdetails', component: AptDetailsComponent, as: 'AptDetails' } // not working as expected 
])
```

When I have a routerLink in apartment page to aptdetails, the page reloads when this link in clicked.

The link from  BusinessUnit to Apartment works as expected. But from Apartment to AptDetails doesn't work as expected.

Any idea what is wrong in the config ?

The RouterLink is in the Apartment component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'apartment',
  template: `
   <div *ngFor="#apartment of apartments" class="demo-updates mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--4-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-desktop">
              <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
                <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">{{apartment.UnitType}}</a>
                <a [routerLink]="['AptDetails']" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect" (click)="getAvailable(apartment)">Available</a>                   
              </div>   
    </div>          
    `,

    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})
```

Comment: If you can go to the `/app/businessunits/aptdetails` directly from the url and everything renders correctly then your `@RouteConfig` is ok. Can you confirm that? If so then give us `routerLink`s you have.

Comment: What happens if you change the order, put second  { path: '/aptdetails', component: AptDetailsComponent, as: 'AptDetails' }

Comment: @WojciechKwiatek yes I can get to it directly, but the page refreshes when it does go there.

Comment: @AngJobs No difference when I try the change you suggested.

Comment: Where (in what component) is the `routerLink`? How does it look like?

Comment: It is in the apartment component. updated the question

Comment: I found the issue .. it is the click event that is breaking the Routerlink. when I remove the click event, it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to your component structure I think this should work:

```
<a [routerLink]="['../AptDetails']"
```